# Google Sheets: How do I protect a sheet without locking its sheet name?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-protection

I have a Google Sheets workbook in which I need to protect all cells for data purposes. However, I need restricted users to be able to change the tab title of the individual sheets’ names.

Does anyone have a workaround for this?

Comment: Data\Protected sheets and ranges\Add range SheetName!A:X (or whatever last column is) - with check boxes set permissions who can edit cell values. After you are done others would be able only to change sheet name.